# No module named 'app' in absolute path import

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm working on a flask project which has the following structure:

```
└──app
     ├── __init__.py 
     └── main 
          ├── __init__.py
          ├── service
          │   └── __init__.py (empty file)
          │   └── requests_service.py
          ├─── model
          │    └── __init__.py (empty file)
          │    └── models.py
          └─── util
               └── __init__.py (empty file)
               └── dto.py
└── requirements.txt
└── .gitignore
```

**IN THE `__init__.py` INSIDE THE APP FOLDER**

```
from app.main.service.requests_service import RequestsManager
```

Result:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

**In the `dto.py` inside the util folder**

```
from app.main.model.models import News
```

Result:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Basically every module I try to import results in the same error, shown above. I feel like this should be an easy fix, but can't get me head around it. Any help?

Comment: Are you running Python from the parent directory of app?

Comment: @Pat-Laugh I am

Comment: A fix is doing something like`sys.path.insert(0, root path of app)` before imports, but that's more a hack. Best make sure your Flask app is properly configured. I had that problem once with a Flask, but I don't remember exactly the solution

Comment: What arguments are you passing to `python`?

Comment: @DavisHerring I managed to get it working by inserting a file outside of the app folder, as an entry point for the project. Thanks anyway.